# I have a superclass that is Comparable, but a grandchild is not

Tags: java

I am implementing an hierarchy with the class definitions as follows:

`public interface SomeInterface<T extends SomeInterface<T>> extends Comparable<T> {...}`

Then,

`public abstract class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>> extends SomeInterface<T>{...}`

And finally,

`public class SomeChild extends SomeClass<SomeChild>{...}`

For a SomeChild s, `s instanceof Comparable` returns false.

I want to be able to call `Collections.sort()` on an ArrayList of SomeChilds, but running it throws a compile-time error of a `ClassCastException` because SomeChild cannot be cast to a Comparable and I'm scratching my head as to why. If a superclass extends Comparable, why can't its child?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @RalphAouad the code isn't necessary no? All that's needed is the class definitions afaik

Comment: @Joesteffy it matters if you want us to reproduce the exception you're getting.

Comment: @Joesteffy - The other alternative would be to close your question as "not reproducible".  Because the "code" in your question at the moment clearly doesn't compile.  And when we fix the errors, it doesn't behave in the way you describe.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Even though my answer got some upvotes, I have to agree with @StephenC.  We don't currently know what the problem was with the OPs code.  I guess I COULD argue the other way by saying that my answer does answer the Title of the question, by saying "Yes It Is". :).- I'd like to see the question improved, as I'm curious what the problem really was.

Answer (score 3):

The code you show will not compile.  The snippet:

```
extends SomeInterface<T>
```

should be:

```
implements SomeInterface<T>
```

Once you make that change, this code:

```
SomeChild s = new SomeChild();
if (s instanceof Comparable)
    System.out.println("Yup!");
```

WILL print "Yup!" because SomeChild must be a Comparable since its ancestors are, as you expect.  Is your `s` possibly `null`?  If it were, then "Yup!" would not print because `null` is not an instance of anything, and so this code:

```
SomeChild s = null;
if (s instanceof Comparable)
    System.out.println("Yup!");
```

will not print anything.